# Implementing a secure confirmation page for an entity form (D8)

Tags: forms, 8, entities, users

I have a custom entity that is used for user submissions. Anonymous users will be able to submit confidential information using the entity add form. After submission I want to show some kind of confirmation page (Thank you for submitting etc.), but I'm not sure what is the best way to achieve this. The user should also receive a similar confirmation by email.

I was thinking of simply adding a view mode `confirmation` to the entity and have the form redirect to that page on submit, but I am concerned about access control here: visitors would be able to view other user's submissions, if they simply try random entity ids. Is there a way to restrict access to visitors who just submitted the form?

Answer (score 2):

In drupal there are several way to do the same thing.
What I suggest in this case (certainly different for another person) use a small custom module with Cookies or Session.

1. Create a custom module.
2. Add an extra submitter.

   - Save the new USER ID on session, cookie ...
   - Redirect to the page (Ex : `$form_state->setRedirect('your.module.route.name');`)
3. Create a small dynamic custom page (Like : http://www.drupal8.ovh/en/tutoriels/5/create-a-simple-module-for-drupal-8-step-2-create-simple-page)

   - Get the USER ID from session, cookie ...

You can change the confirmation mail template from back office.

Comment: Sounds good so far - so what do you mean by 'extra submitter'? Do you mean create a user account?

Comment: So, the key point here is to use session variables in order to restrict access to the confirmation page and related data, correct? User ID won't work, since I have to address anonymous visitors, too, but I could save the ID of the newly created entity in a session variable. Would you consider that safe?